# QSqlError("',"',"',) In QT widget app

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am making an ATM app but for some reason when the code is executed to display the users balance, it doesnt properly fetch the value from the database.  it throws the error `QSqlError(""'."",""')`.

```
class bankfn : public QObject{
public:

    int getCheq(QString e){
        QSqlDatabase myDB = QSqlDatabase::database("myConnection",true);
        QSqlQuery qry(myDB);

        qry.prepare("SELECT cheqBal FROM userRecords WHERE email = (:email)");
        qry.bindValue(":email",e);
        qDebug() << qry.lastError();
        return qry.exec();
    }

    int getSav(QString e){
        QSqlDatabase myDB = QSqlDatabase::database("myConnection",true);
        QSqlQuery qry(myDB);

        qry.prepare("SELECT savbal FROM userRecords WHERE email = (:email)");
        qry.bindValue(":email",e);
        qDebug() << qry.lastError();
        return qry.exec();
    }

    void setCheq(QString e);
    void setSav(QString e);
};


void maunMenu::setupLogin() //Set up login page for after user credential check
{
   ui->cheqbalL->setText("$"+bank.getCheq(sm.activeUser()));
   ui->savBalL->setText("$"+bank.getSav(sm.activeUser()));
}
```

Comment: In both cases here, you're checking for an error before executing the query. It doesn't look like that's mentioned in the documentation, but I would expect that to be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it seems you are not getting any errors. You are trying to print a no error situation.

Your `exec()` function call returns a `bool` value.

If you want to track an error, Check for the `bool` value returned by `exec()` statement first.

The `exec()` function returns false, in case of query execution failure.

**Should be somewhat as shown below:**

```
int getCheq(QString e){
..
..
..
..
       bool error = qry.exec();

       //HANDLE THE ERROR IF THE EXEC RETURNS FALSE
       if(!error)       
         qDebug() << qry.lastError();

       return isErrored ;
}
```

More over your `getCheq` function returns , if the execution of query is success or not. It will not return the value you expect.

You have to return the value of query result.

Change the function return type to `double`

And you can return the value from query as shown below.

```
return qry.value(0).toDouble();
```

*Note: Take care of NULL checks before returning values/accessing members.*

Comment: i added the qry.value(0).toDouble but it just puts 0 in the textbox and returns QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record.

Comment: It seems your query not returning a record. Also do not put return inside the else. Just put it outside. your query is executed successfully.